Would this subfloor condensation damage require extensive repair?
We had a home inspected and they noticed that the sub-floor is web near the duct registers where they lack proper insulation. I am curious if adding insulation and drying the wood be enough to repair this issue or if the subfloor should be replaced.
Image Below:
https://imgur.com/aCK5Jcj

only someone that can physically examine the subfloor can answer your question

Did you mean to type "wet" instead of "web"?

Yes, it is wet to the touch
